# How do i insert a NULL value into an integer column using python and mysql.connector

Tags: python, mysql, null, mysql-connector

The column doesn't have constraints such as NOT NULL and, since I'm using python, I tried to insert None instead of NULL. It still doesn't work. Can anyone help?

How the table was created:

```
create_species = "CREATE TABLE `species` (" \
             "  `{}` varchar(40) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL," \
             "  `{}` varchar(40) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL," \
             "  `{}` varchar(40) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL," \
             "  `{}` varchar(40) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL," \
             "  `{}` varchar(70) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL," \
             "  `{}` varchar(40) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL," \
             "  `{}` varchar(40) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL," \
             "  `{}` int(20)," \
             "  `{}` varchar(40) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL," \
             "  `{}` varchar(40) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL," \
```

How I insert in the table:

```
"INSERT INTO species (name, classification, designation, average_height, skin_colors, hair_colors, eye_colors, average_lifespan, language, homeworld)"
              "VALUES ('{}', '{}', '{}', '{}', '{}', '{}', '{}', '{}', '{}', '{}');".format(row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4], row[5], row[6], row[7], row[8], row[9])
```

Where row[7] is in some cases an integer (that's when it works) and in other cases it has the value "NA", so I transform it into None as follows:

```
if row[7] == "NA":
  row[7] = None
```

The value has to be NULL otherwise avg() and other similar operations will give me a wrong result.

Comment: You'd insert nothing into the field and if there's no default, it'll resort to null if you didn't force NOT NULL.

Comment: "I tried to insert None instead of NULL. It still doesn't work"—please show us this attempt. And please read [ask].

Comment: @Chris I added the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please don't build queries like this:

```py
"INSERT INTO foo VALUES ({}, {}, {})".format(1, "bar", None)
```

Assuming the values `1`, `"bar"`, and `None` come from an untrusted source, this leaves you open to a very serious type of software vulnerability called [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Most sources of data should be considered untrusted, and writing queries safely should always be the default.

There is another problem with the above query: it is wrong. This generates

```sql
INSERT INTO foo VALUES (1, bar, None)
```

which is missing quotes around `bar` (strings should be quoted as `'bar'`) and it uses `None` where it should use `NULL`.

The [correct way to do this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-example-cursor-transaction.html) is to pass the parameters `1`, `"bar"`, and `None` to your database separately:

```py
parameters = (1, "bar", None)
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO foo VALUES (%s, %s, %s)", parameters)

# or you can name parameters

parameter_dict = {
    "first": 1,
    "second": "bar",
    "third": None,
}
cursor.execute(
    "INSERT INTO foo VALUES (%(first)s, %(second)s, %(third)s)", 
    parameter_dict,
)
```

This protects against SQL injection and also takes care of quoting strings, converting `None` to `NULL`, etc.

Finally, you can just skip values that should be null (or use the default value for the column) and let MySQL fill them in for you, e.g.

```sql
INSERT INTO foo (first, second) VALUES (1, 'bar');
```

Comment: Thank you! Skipping solved my problem, but I can see how the other solutions are also good. I wasn't aware of the problems with the .format() queries.